# How to use tensorflow dataset to fit a tf.keras model? why do I need to batch?

Tags: model, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, dimension, tf.dataset

When following the recommended way to create a dataset from numpy arrays via

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xdata, ydata))`

the way to fit the model

`model.fit(dataset)`

creates the following error

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3, 2), found shape=(3, 2)`

the dataset is created via

```
   xdata = np.zeros((observations, datapoints, features), dtype="float16")
    ydata = np.zeros((observations, classes), dtype="float16")
    for i in range(observations):
        xdata[i, :, :] = np.random.rand(datapoints, features)
        ydata[i, :] = np.random.rand(classes)
```

for a model with input layer

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, 3, input_shape = (datapoints,features,)))
```

with

```
datapoints=3
features=2
```

So the input is 2 dimensional and xdata and ydata are packed into one dataset.

for executable code see [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/fabfabifabfabi/fit-issue)

To boil the issue down to the simplest toy problem still producing the error see [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/fabfabifabfabi/fit-issue))

The internet research was not very revealing.
Unfortunately all the official examples for fitting use two separate inputs.

For earlier versions of TF, there was the now deprecated [.make_one_shot_iterator()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29252). Now it is possible to direclty iterate through a dataset. Unfortunately, this seems to not work for the fit method.

Interestingly, the official [Keras documentation for the fit method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) states

x: Input data. could be:

`A tf.data.Dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).`

The same error is raised for tf.keras and for keras.

I found the solution here: [keras.Model.compute_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compute_loss)

Now the question: Why is `batch()` needed in order for the fit call to work?